# How to properly call controller/action in Zend Framework 1?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

I have the following directory structure in a Zend Framework 1 application:

```
application/
├── controllers/
│   └── admin/
│     └── TaxRateController.php
│   └── MainInitController.php
```

I am trying to access `taxrate` which should be `indexAction()` but I am doing something wrong since I am getting a `Zend_Controller_Action_Exception`. This is what I have tried all this URL combination so far:

```
http://localhos/admin/tax-rate/index
http://localhos/admin/tax-rate
http://localhos/admin/taxrate
http://localhos/admin/taxrate/index
```

And all of them generates the same error:

> [message:protected] => Action "taxRate" does not exist and was not
>   trapped in __call()

This is the content of the class(es):

```
class TaxRateController extends MainInitController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'I am here'; die();
    }
}

class MainInitController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    ....
}
```

What I am missing here? How I should be calling the `controller/action`?

**Update 1:**

I have tried to move the directory outside `controllers` but the result is the same:

```
application/
│   └── admin/
│     └── TaxRateController.php
├── controllers/
│   └── MainInitController.php
```

I am calling as `http://localhost/admin/taxrate` in this scenario.

Comment: Been a while since I've used Zend, but the error makes it appear that it's looking for ACTION taxRate, NOT controller tax rate, I believe in your AdminController you need to define a taxrateAction() also, you might need to change TaxRateController to TaxrateController, Zend gets very particular on camel casing. pattern is overridable, but usual /controller/view so admin = controller taxrate = view

Comment: If admin is not a controller, you need to create a module.  Zend acts with `/module/controller/action` if you don't have any modules it will look for `/controller/action` pattern.

Comment: @dpp `Admin` isn't a controller but a folder inside `controllers` directory.

Comment: @mim. I have tried moving the directory `admin` outside controllers but then I end up with the same error, take a look to the edit on the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With basic structure it will take time and effort to do that but it can be done

```
application/
├── controllers
│   └── admin
│       └── TaxRateController.php
```

You need to create routes for every controller under sub directory in your bootstrap:

```
public function _initAdminRoute()
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

    // structure
    $router->addRoute(
            'unique_route_name',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/admin/controllerRoute/:action/*', 
                ['controller' => 'subdirName_controllerRoute']
            )
    );

    // Like this
    $router->addRoute(
            'admin_taxrate_route',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/admin/tax-rate/:action/*', ['controller' => 'admin_tax-rate'])
    );
}
```

After this you need to rename your controller classes with subdirectory name to let zend find them. But do not change controller file names.

```
class TaxRateController => class Admin_TaxRateController
```

Now you can use your controllers, but a little fix may be needed for your views cause right now zend can not find your view directory. You need to move all your admin views to admin subdirectory or it will throw an error something similar to this.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'script 'admin/tax-rate/action.phtml' not found in path (application/views/scripts/)' in

Hope this helps, but still i will recommend using module structure.

Comment: I think this solution could work, I haven't time to try right now because I'm on a deadline but I will asap and I will let you know if it works or no. Until them I will leave the question open to new answer but I am tempted to accept your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

If 'admin' is a module you should use a directory structure like this:

```
application/
├── modules
│   └── admin
|       └── controllers
│           └── TaxRateController.php
```

Also make sure your `application/configs/application.ini` is according with it:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/"
```

**Edit**

Be sure your file `public/index.php` ends like this:

```
$application = new Zend_Application(
     APPLICATION_ENV,
     APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
        ->run();
```

Comment: Well `admin` isn't a module at all but is the backend side of the application, I want to order the classes properly so I not end up with many of them under `controllers` directory, that's it. I think built modules is change how the application behaves and my boss will not be happy with this solution, any other advise?

Comment: BTW not even this way is working, same result as in the OP

Comment: Strange. My ZF1 applications work with that. Could you show your application.ini file?

Comment: I don't have such file :-\

Comment: It's why is not working. Create it in the directoty above and make sure your application is created using it. I will edit the answer. To show how

Comment: This is a huge application, how that change would affect this? The application has been working without such file and config for years now so I am not so sure about play with this at this time. The idea is to improve the old code but they are resistant to the change ...

Comment: I understand, but this is not a huge change. If they think so, you should consider @mim answer instead.